# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {x,y,z}

Tags: react-native, parameters, navigation

I'm trying to open another screen that retrive info from firbase DB through passing the userID as a parameter in the navigation function 
in this way

```
<TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('User',{userId: item.autherId})}>
                     <Image source={{uri: item.url}}
                     style={{resizeMode: 'cover',width: '100%',height: 275}}/>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
```

but i get this error whenehever i press the photo
[screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lglfj.png)

Comment: try to `console log` the value of `item.url` ... and check if it's a valid uri

Comment: another thing if the `url` is valid ... you need to manually specify a dimensions for your Image like ` style={{width: 50, height: 50}}` ... as long as it's a network Image

Comment: This problem is because the image source is receiving an object instead of a link. Make sure your item.url is destructured and passing the correct string value.